# How to change 200 ok status of 404 error page in expressionengine?

Tags: ee

I have my custom 404 page in expression-engine but is display 200 ok status so i want to set 404 status on console can you please help me

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set the 404 template in your template Global Preferences? Once this is set, EE uses a 404 status when returning the 404 template.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the HTTP Header add-on for this: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header